# Android customized toast

Tags: android, toast

> Looking for customize toast as :

1. Size of Toast according to need.
2. Colour of Toast.
3. Position of Toast.
4. And time of Toast according to need(i.e it will appear for 5 second or 6 second).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16909532/1752867 here are the same question and answer.

Comment: thank you so much keysan,i got my all answer from here.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom layout of your choice of `Toast` loook and feel.

**custom_toast.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/custom_toast_layout_id"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FFF"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:textColor="#000" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And add the following piece of code inside Oncreate() button click

```
 button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonToast);

            button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {

                    // get your custom_toast.xml ayout
                    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();

                    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_toast,
                      (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.custom_toast_layout_id));

                    // set a dummy image
                    ImageView image = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.image);
                    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

                    // set a message
                    TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.text);
                    text.setText("Button is clicked!");

                    // Toast...
                    Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
                    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
                    toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    toast.setView(layout);
                    toast.show();


}
        });
```

When you click on the button, you will see the customized `Toast` Message.

Thanks to http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-toast-example/

Answer (score 0):

To make custom toast on click events it just simple.
Just Go through android developer site - http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html#CustomToastView%20

or you can check this sample Toast tutorial - http://androiddesk.wordpress.com/2012/01/28/custom-notification-in-android-with-an-example/